# What affect, if any, would buying domain names with high volume search terms have on SEO?

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, googlebot, pagerank

Assume the following:

- I have a website: `www.example.com`.
- I want to rank `www.example.com/searc-term-1` on the first page of Google.

Would it help the SEO of `www.example.com/searc-term-1` if I bought the domain name `www.searc-term-1.com` or `www.search-term-1.net` and had them 301 redirect to `www.example.com/searc-term-1`?

OR instead

Would it help the SEO of `www.example.com/searc-term-1` if I bought the domain name `www.searc-term-1.com` or `www.search-term-1.net` and had content on them relevant to `search-term-1` and placed a `do-follow` link to `www.example.com/searc-term-1`?

Is the a blackhat practice?

Comment: Major league blackhat. It will not work. There are no shortcuts and search engines will ping the snot out of you possibly forever for trying.

Comment: CP30@ All the new domain is empty bucket, you can't get any water from it. Hope that simple logic clear your future question :)

Answer (score 3):

If I was forced to pick one of your options, I'd choose the first, because then you're directing the users to one place, but personally, I'd save my money and not buy another domain.

Instead, use your existing URL:

```
www.example.com/searc-term-1
```

then in your HTML code for the above URL, talk about `searc-term-1` and include it in your HTML title tag meta-description tag and header tag, but don't overdo it or your page will look too spammy. Run your page through various SEO tools on the net to make sure it is done right.